# WPF cannot find static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an element defined in a resource dictionary like so:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ChromeBrush" Color="Red"  />
```

I'm trying to use this as the background of a `Border` as shown below:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolBar">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolBar">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource ChromeBrush}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToolBarPanel x:Name="PART_ToolBarPanel" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="0,1,2,2" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For this specific usage I get an error saying `Cannot find resource named 'ChromeBrush'. Resource names are case sensitive`.

If I change the static resource usage to just `Red` all works as expected.

The User Control that is hosting the Toolbar is being dynamically created at runtime (via `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`) - In case it helps, the XAML for the User Control is:

```
<framework:PanelBase x:Class="Framework.UserControl1"
            namespaces omitted for brevity
            >

    <framework:PanelBase.ToolbarTemplate>
        <ToolBar />
    </framework:PanelBase.ToolbarTemplate>

    <!-- other controls -->
</framework:PanelBase>
```

The bizarre thing is that the brush is used elsewhere in the project a number of times in various controls in exactly the same way with no issues (some usages are actually on the hosting User Control). In the snippet above, Visual Studio underlines the resource in the correct colour so *it* is able to resolve it.

**UPDATE:**
After wondering if it's something to do with the fact that the UserControl1 class is in a different (dynamically loaded) assembly to the resource dictionary, I tried using the resource on another control and it works fine... something specifically to do with that Toolbar style.

```
<framework:PanelBase x:Class="Framework.UserControl1"
            namespaces omitted for brevity
            >

    <framework:PanelBase.ToolbarTemplate>
        <ToolBar />
    </framework:PanelBase.ToolbarTemplate>

    <Border Background="{StaticResource ChromeBrush}">
        <!-- WORKS FINE! -->
    </Border>
</framework:PanelBase>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening at runtime for this specific usage? Is the fact that it's dynamically created got anything to do with it?

Thanks in advance,
Scott

Comment: NVM, runtime. Creating it via Activator probably is the issue. That's a nutty way to use user controls in an application. I'm guessing you're not using MVVM?  Typically you'd define your UC in a DataTemplate and let content controls pick it up as needed...

Comment: I sort of doubt it because the PanelBase style in another resource dictionary is also referencing the brush as a static resource and that is fine. I'm reading layout from a file and and dynamically loading instances of "panels" from "plugin assemblies"

Comment: Does DynamicResource work?

Comment: YES! What the hell? Why does DynamicResource only work there for for _that_ user control, but StaticResource works everywhere else? (Including _inside_ the user control??

Comment: As great as it is that it's unblocked me, I'd love to know _why_

Comment: I’m not sure, that is strange behavior, but probably has to do with when and how the framework does the binding/lookup for static resources, for example you can load in resource dictionaries dynamically at runtime, but you can only reference them using DynamicResource

Comment: Hah, DynamicResource to the rescue.

Comment: Yet another quirk of WPF that doesn't make any sense to me! (I don't use it all that often, but whenever I do I _always_ find it utterly bizarre and completely non-intuitive) :) Thanks for the help... if you want the rep, post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess for the reason that it doesn’t work is some quirk of how and when WPF looks up and binds static resources. My guess is that it has more do with how you load the assembly than how you instantiate the object (via reflection with `Activator.CreateInstance`), but I could be totally off, someone more familiar with WPF internals would have to say for sure.

However, the workaround should be simple: use `DynamicResource` instead. `DynamicResource` works more like normal bindings and should have no trouble resolving the references.

Comment: Thanks, DynamicResource works for me in this instance... I still find it very confusing when you _have_ to use DynamicResource over StaticResource when one works _most_ of the time (despite reading the documentation!)